# Need to convert old 32-bit GAS code to a current GAS assembler (pushfl/popl)

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I am in the process of trying to compile an old project on my modern machine. I know this old project used an old (2.x) version of GCC/GAS so I need to clean it up so that I can compile it with a current version.

The code in question:

```
__get_flags:
    pushfl
    popl %eax
    ret
```

`gas` complains that `pushfl` is not an instruction. From what I read this is an old deprecated GNU mnemonic, but there must be some sort of x86_64 equivalent, surely?

In addition to answering how to convert this code to x86_64 gas, it would be great if someone could explain where mnemonics like `pushfl` and `pushfq` and defined and documented. I am quite sure that are GAS creations...

Note: I want to compile this on gcc 4.6.1 and gas 2.21

Answer (score 2):

The following:

```
static inline u16 __get_flags(void) {
    u16 flags;
    asm ("pushf\n\t"
         "pop %0" : : "+r"(flags) : "cc");
    return flags;
}
```

should actually be *portable* for both 64/32bit, x64/x86. But it only gets you the condition codes, not the high parts of the state register. If you require the entire contents of the flags register when running in 64bit (long) mode, use the `PUSHFQ` instruction name, with a `u64` (or other 64bit quantity) operand.

Comment: If I were to do this strictly from assembly, which register would I `pop` to? In the original example it was `eax`, however when I try that here (after a `pushf`) I get an error: `Error: operand type mismatch for `pop'`. Thanks!

Comment: I just read that all stack operations on x86_64 are implicitly 64 bit, so no 32 bit counterparts are available, however 16 bit ones are. http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html

Comment: yes you're correct `push`/`pop` in x86_64 are 64bit or else explicitly overrideable to 16bit, that's the main difference, no 32bit push/pop when running in 64bit mode; when you use gcc inline assembly, you don't have to specify the register name but can use the placeholders, hence it's possible to create code in certain situations that doesn't depend on the width/name of a register. It'd be helpful to get a little more context about what your code uses the above function for ...

Comment: Re your first comment, if you have to do this as assembly sources, use register `%rax`. It depends on how strict the expectations of the code calling the above are Whether you need to `movzwl %ax, %eax` (to mask the lower 16bit out) or whether you need to explicitly clear the high 32bits (`mov %eax, eax` would do so, special property of long mode that 32bit ops clear the high bits of a 64bit reg) to make sure any reserved/undefined high bits in the flags are definitely zero (If the C prototype is `unsigned int __get_flags();` then a simple `pushf; pop %rax; ret` is ok).

Comment: This is not portable to the System V x86-64 ABI as it overwrites the red zone.

Comment: @Timotyh Baldwin: I'm too strongly on the kernel programming side where the redzone doesn't apply, apologies. You could bracket it with a 'skip redzone' `subq $0x100, %rsp` / `addq $0x100, %rsp` pair, or make it a _never inline_ function (to stop callers from using a redzone). Alternatively ... use gcc 5.x, which has `__readeflags()` as a builtin, as per https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/d91f949bee59344edfe3f78123892807a9486c60

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment to the answer because I don't have 50 reputation. Anyway:

In the answer:

```
"pop %0" : : "+r"(flags) : "cc");
```

Should read:

```
"pop %0" : "=r"(flags) : : "cc");
```

Because the syntax is `asm( code : outputs : inputs : clobbers )` and what you want is flags to be a register that's output from the asm block, not used as input. (I tested this and it worked for me, I also used 64-bit ints)